# regular functions definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the literature there appear to be two different definitions of "regular functions":

1. defined locally by polynomials
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_algebraic_varieties
2. defined locally by rational functions as a well defined quotient of polynomials about each point.
   [https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019-c2.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019-c2.pdf)

how does changing the definition of regular function affect the theory? Can I just assume the first definition?

Comment: The second link does not work.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to define what it means for a function to be regular on an *open subset* of an affine variety, you must you definition 2: a function is regular on this open subset iff it can locally be written as a ratio of polynomials with non-vanishing denominators.

In the special case where you're defining what it means for a function to be regular on the *entire* affine variety, this is equivalent to definition 1: a function is regular on the entire affine variety iff it can globally be written as a polynomial. And yes, I do mean "globally", not "locally".